# VS 2008, deploying application with resource folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

I am using Visual Studio 2008 on a C# project. My programs requires around 300 data files (txt, dbf and csv mostly). I use a post build command line to copy those files into the output directory (so far so good).

```
MKDIR $(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)system
XCOPY $(ProjectDir)system $(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)system /S /Y
```

I also have a deployment project to facilitate the program installation on my users' computers. My problem is that I cannot find a way to make the installer copy the "system" directory from my project output directory into the installation directory.

I have tryed the following:

1. to script (postbuild event) the directory copy from the program project to the deployment output like this (working):

   ```
   MKDIR "$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\system"
   XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)..\Track\bin\x64\$(Configuration)\system" "$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\system" /S /Y
   ```
2. to script the directory copy from the deployment programm execution folder to the installation directory. Something like this:

   ```
   MKDIR "$(InstallationDir))\system" XCOPY "$(DeploymentAppDirectory)\system" "$(IstallationDir)\system" /S /Y
   ```

But I cannot figure how to make the second point.

I am really stuck now, an hint would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try move your "system" dir to solution level instead project level and use `$(SolutionDir)system` in both post build events.

Comment: I thought about doing that one day or another but it does not change anything because: 1. The problem does not concerns the post-build scripts but how to make the installation program copy this directory 2. $(SolutionDir) does not exist for deployment project on visual studio 2008. (but that was worth a try)